# JHipster: Create Default Project With MSSQL Not Working

Tags: jhipster

I followed the install instructions for jhipster and was able to run the command

```
jhipster
```

I then followed the prompts in the CLI on Ubuntu selecting MicroSoftSQL for the database. When I launch localhost:8080 and try to login with "admin" "admin" nothing happens. I looked at the logs and see an error with liquidbase saying a connection was refused for microsoft sql.

My questions:

1. Before running "jhipster" command do I need to install and have my MS
   SQL sever running and started?
2. Does JHipster need a database set up before hand ignorer to create a table for the user "admin" "admin"?
3. I could not find any docs on the database install part before running jhipster, could someone point me somewhere with a MS SQL setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JHipster has a front facing angular interface when you first build an application using JHipster cli. I found that that interface needs a dB setup so that it can store admin accounts for logging in. When using the JHipster cli you can select in memory database for this. Then when you deploy you can change the configuration so that it uses you real main database.

Answer (score 2):

1. No, when create one app with jhipster, you don't need one database running, it's necessary only when **start** your app and this use database like mysql, msql, h2 in memory, etc.
2. Jhipster with database, need configuration. You configuration must be in the application-*.yml (datasource property), jhipster **automatically** create tables for the user admin.
3. I don't understand, you want examples? Here : [Jhipster with MSSQL](http://www.jhipster.tech/tips/004_tip_using_ms_sql_server.html)
   Regards.